# Disabling validators on form for adding child forms without javascript

Tags: php, symfony

What would be the best way to temporarily disable validators on form. Consider following

MyController.php

```
$builder = $this->createFormBuilder()
           ->add('parentfield1')
           ->add('parentfield2')
           ->add('children', 'collection', array('type' => new ChildType(), 'allow_add' => true));

$form = $builder->getForm();

if ($request->request->get('addb')) { 
    $formReq = $request->request->get('form');

    $formReq['children'][] = array(
        'child_id' => '1',
        'childfield1' => '',
        'childfield2' => ''
    );



    $request->request->set('form', $formReq);

    // I would like to disable validators here somehow
    $form->bindRequest($request);
} elseif ($request->request->get('sendb')) {
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    // persist form to database
}
```

So in my form I have two different buttons:
sendb - that posts the form, validates it and persists to database
addb - that just posts the form and adds new fields for adding child items without calling validators

Currently I can do this with validation groups:

```
$validationGroups = array();
if($request->request->get('addb')) {
    // I just use group not defined in entity for any validators
    $validationGroups[] = 'novalidation';
}

$builder = createFormBuilder(new ParentEntity(), array('validation_groups' => $validationGroups));
```

This works but this also means code duplication since symfony2 only allows to pass validators into form builder constructor and I have to check request->get('addb') twice.

I do know that adding child form fields can also be done with javascript (collection prototype option) but I want to get it working without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can set validation groups dynamically based on submitted data in `setDefaultOptions` method. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-submitted-data).

Comment: Thanks. I do know that it is possible to specify closure as value for validation_groups but I do not really see how it helps to avoid checking request type twice, maybe I am missing something. But I did realise that I can at least avoid hard coding the request parameter twice by introducing variable:

`$isAddReq = $request->request->get('addb');`

and checking by this variable instead.

Still interested by other possible options.

Comment: You can add a listener on `FormEvents::PRE_BIND` event and move your field addition code there. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html) for more info.